# Move center map in pixels

Tags: react-leaflet

I have a react-leaflet map with markers. When I click on any marker, it is centered, and a pop-up opens. This pop-up has a height of 300px, and that's why I would like to move the center of the map -115px above the Y-axis.

This is my `ChangeView` component, in charge of positioning the map.

```
import { useMap } from "react-leaflet/hooks";

const ChangeView = ({
  center,
  zoom,
}) => {
  const map = useMap();
  map.setView(center, zoom);

  return null;
};

export default ChangeView;
```

I tried to add a Pan after the map centering, but it doesn't work as I expect. The first marker is centered correctly, but then when I move to other markers, the centering is completely wrong.

```
map.setView(center, zoom).panBy([0, -115]);
```

I would like the center of the map to always be 115 pixels lower than the original center, and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: A possible solution would be to convert the `center - (0, -115px)` in a new point based on Zoom but idk how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the answer:

Using two methods from `react-leaflet map` i could move the map.

- I convert my center (in coords) in a center in px.
- Then i subtract 150px from y-axis.
- Now i convert this new point in coords.
- Finally i apply the new center moved 150px.

  ```
  import { useMap } from "react-leaflet/hooks";

  const ChangeView = ({
    center,
    zoom,
  }) => {

    const map = useMap();
    const centerInPx = map.latLngToContainerPoint(center);

    const newCenterInPx = {
      ...centerInPx,
      y: centerInPx.y - 150,
    };

    const newCenterInCoords = map.containerPointToLatLng(newCenterInPx);

    map.setView(newCenterInCoords, zoom);

    return null;
  };

  export default ChangeView;
  ```